# DataSnapshot value of the current user is NULL

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the name and phone for the current user from the Non Member node.But for some reason I'm always getting the value for name and phone to be NULL. I debugged and traced it back to find that the Value of the DataSnapshot for the current user is NULL.

Code :

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("NonMember");
        final FirebaseUser Key = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final String userKey = Key.getUid();

        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MEMBERMAINActivity.class));
        }

        myRef.child(userKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                   Log.d("TAG", "Name"+ name);
                  // profile_name.setText(name);
                }}


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MyProfile.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The keys you have in the database under "NonMember" are not Firebase Auth user IDs.  They look like Realtime Database push IDs, which means you've likely added the user data with something like `myRef.push().setValue(...)`. However, your code is attempting to use a user ID to locate user data.  The ID you're getting from Firebase Auth is just not matching the data in the database.  If your query doesn't match any data, then it will get a null value in the snapshot.

If you want to store per-user data, don't use a Realtime Database push operation - use the ID of the user, with something like `myRef.child(userKey).setValue(...)`.

Comment: I understood my problem, Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   String name = ds.child("name").getValue().toString();
                   Log.d("TAG", "Name"+ name);
                  // profile_name.setText(name);
                }
```

try this